# Not sure how to prevent the scrollbar rendering automatically with content in react app

Tags: javascript, html, css, antd

[The content is being rendered this way in the browser, along with the scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep0CW.jpg)

[This is how the modal scrolling looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TITnK.jpg)

```
const [visiblee, setVisiblee] = useState(false);

const showModall = () => {
           setVisiblee(true)
                           };

const handleOKK = e => {
            console.log(e);
            setVisiblee(false);
                         }

const handleCancell = e => {
                console.log(e);
                setVisiblee(false);
                             };

<Button style={{float: 'right'}} type="primary" onClick={showModall}>
                SQLQuery
              </Button>
              <Modal class="adjust"
                visible={visiblee}
                onOk={handleOKK}
                onCancel={handleCancell}
                width={1000}
                bodyStyle={{height:1000}}
              >
              <p>
                  <p><JSONPretty id="json-pretty" data={response}></JSONPretty></p>
              </p>
              </Modal>
              <StyledDividerr type="vertical"/><JSONPretty id="json-pretty" data={response}></JSONPretty>{renderChart(component)({ ...renderProps, pivotConfig })}
```

[I want to display the sql this way-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZkmz.jpg)
this modal is from antd.

I guess I need to format the SQL, maybe? Is there a way to vertical scroll this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to style the div so it has a fixed witdth, fixed height and overflow scroll property.

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll; //vertical scorlling
    overflow-x: scroll; //horizontal scroll  
}
```

This is a example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmecutg3/2/

Comment: is there a way to vertical scroll this?

Comment: I have added vertical and horizontal scroll. Is that what you have meant?